# Cómo puedo adjuntar un excel al Mail con fast-excel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

```
    public static function generateCsv($request) {
        $number_of_clinics_sending_samples = collect(DB::select(Self::NUMBER_OF_CLINICS_SENDING_SAMPLES, [1]));
        $number_of_labs_analyzing_samples = collect(DB::select(Self::NUMBER_OF_LABS_ANALYZING_SAMPLES, [1]));

        $sinceCollectionToReportSendingData =  Self::getSinceCollectionToReportSendingData($request);
        array_push($sinceCollectionToReportSendingData, 'Since collection to report sending');    

        $sinceSampleReceipAtLabToReportSending =  Self::getSinceSampleReceipAtLabToReportSending($request);
        array_push($sinceSampleReceipAtLabToReportSending, 'Since samples receipt at lab to report sending');

        $numberOfSamplePerMont = Self::getNumberOfSamplePerMont($request);
        $patientsPerMonth = Self::getPatientsPerMonth($request);
        $patientsPerState = Self::getNumberOfPatientsPerState($request);

        $samplesByQuality = collect(Self::getSamplesByQuality($request));

        $samplesData = array(
            ['Total of samples' => $samplesByQuality['totalOfSamples'][0]->n_samples,
            'Good quality' => $samplesByQuality['goodQuality'][0]->n_samples,
            'Good quality no result' => $samplesByQuality['goodQualityNoResult'][0]->n_samples,
            'Bad quality' => $samplesByQuality['badQuality'][0]->n_samples]
        );
        $samplesCollection = collect($samplesData);
        
        $sheets = new SheetCollection([
            $number_of_clinics_sending_samples,
            $number_of_labs_analyzing_samples,
            [$sinceCollectionToReportSendingData, $sinceSampleReceipAtLabToReportSending],
            $numberOfSamplePerMont,
            $samplesCollection,
            $patientsPerMonth,
            $patientsPerState
        ]);
        $dataCenterName = Self::nameFile($request);

        $date = Date('Y-m-d');
        $fileName = 'dashboard_data'.$request->from.'_'.$request->to.'_'.$date.'_'.$dataCenterName.'.xlsx';
        
        $subject = "Monthly report from m|z";
        $excel = (new FastExcel($sheets))->download($fileName);

        Storage::put('mierda.txt', $excel);
        
        $mail = Mail::to(env('salesmail', 'oscar@gmail.com'));

        $extras = [ 
            'from' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->from)),
            "to" => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->to))
        ];
        // Storage::disk('local')->put($fileName, $excel);

        $viewWithData = new Email("administrator.emails.monthly_report", "", $subject, $extras);
        $viewWithData->attachData($excel, $fileName);

        $mail->send($viewWithData);
        return $excel;
    }
```

Tengo esa funcón, desde el navegador si que me lo descarga bien, pero cuando lo intento ver en el correo me llega con éste contenido:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date:          Tue, 30 Nov 2021 12:46:41 GMT
```

Y ya he intentado con export e import.

Comment: tiene que haber alguna manera de crear el archivo en memoria y adjuntarlo como archivo ... que has intentado al respecto?

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Ya había intentado guardarlo con los los métodos download y export de la clase FastExcel Pero al final lo resolví con la librería Storage.